# getting component id with colon by componentgetClientId(context)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using PF 5.0 and jsf 2.2.8, i have code below.

```
<ui:composition template="/template/mastertemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<f:view>
   <h:body>
    <h:form id="bcr_form_2" styleClass="form">
    <p:tabView id="bcrId_tabview">
    <p:tab title="Budget Cash Demands">
    <h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="save" id="saveDemandId_cmdbutton"
action="#{budgetControlRegisterAction.saveNewDemand()}"
binding="#{budgetControlRegisterAction.myMessageCId}"
update=":#{p:component('saveId_message')}">
</p:commandButton>
<p:message id="saveId_message" for="saveDemandId_cmdbutton" ></p:message>

</h:panelGrid>
</h:form >
<!-- and all closing tags-->
```

**BudgetControlRegisterAction.java class (@ResquestScoped)**

```
    private UIComponent myMessageCId;
    // setter and getter 


    public String saveNewDemand() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    log.info("client Id :" + myMessageCId.getClientId(context));
    //log output is -----> client Id :bcr_form_2:bcrId_tabview:saveDemandId_cmdbutton
    //id on browser is ------>  bcr_form_2:bcrId_tabview:saveDemandId_cmdbutton

/*this is not working */    
    //when i use myMessageCId.getClientId(context) nothing displayed on client side
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(myMessageCId.getClientId(context),new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "some msg" , "some msg"));


/*this is working and displaying msg to client browser*/

    // but when i put hard coded component client Id (copied from web browser) e.g bcr_form_2:bcrId_tabview:saveDemandId_cmdbutton
    // see it is without leading colon (:)
    // and myMessageCId.getClientId(context) gives me id with colon(:) see log output in above lines
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("bcr_form_2:bcrId_tabview:saveDemandId_cmdbutton",new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "some msg" , "some msg"));

    }
```

how can i get client Id (without colon) by myMessageCId.getClientId(context) method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your code (I commented your second `addMessage`, put @RequestScoped and remove `composition`) and it works great on Primefaces 5.1 and Mojarra 2.2.8!
I noticed that your log output is:

```
client Id :bcr_form_2:bcrId_tabview:saveDemandId_cmdbutton
```

But pay attention to log line code:

```
log.info("client Id :" + myMessageCId.getClientId(context));
```

The leading semicolon has been introduced from your string concatenation. So the real output is:

```
bcr_form_2:bcrId_tabview:saveDemandId_cmdbutton
```

and as mentioned above it works.